# Receive parsing XML: unbound prefix error and Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix

Tags: android, xml, prefix

I receive the error messages:

> error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix

Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix

I do not understand why.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >

</EditText>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post full layout XML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this..

android spelling is wrong `andriod` that why **Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix** in this `andriod:hint="@string/edit_message"` line

```
android:hint="@string/edit_message"
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the Attribute problem.
I still receive the error at (Error parsing XML: unbound prefix)
<Edit Text

Comment: @user3423432 do you have string name `edit_message` in `string.xml`

Comment: Yes. I have the edit_message string name in string.xml

Comment: @user3423432 it's impossible it must work. Try to clean your project